# Proof of unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

Assume:
$$ \phi = \int f(x)p(x)dx = E_p(f)$$
Let $x_s \sim p, s=1,.....,S$ iid $(p(x_s=x)=p(x)$ and $p(x_1,x_2) = p(x_1) p(x_2)$.
\begin{align}
\hat{\phi} &= \frac{1}{S}\sum_{s=1}^{S}f(x_s) \\
E[\hat{\phi}] &= \frac{1}{S} \sum_{s=1}^{S}\int f(x_s) p(x_s) dx_s \\
               &= \frac{1}{S} \sum_{s=1}^{S}E(f(x_s)) = \phi 
\end{align}
So, we can call $\hat{\phi}$ as the unbiased estimator of $\phi$.

But how can $E(f(x_1)) = E(f(x_2))$...$=E(f(x_S))$ all be equal in order to get $\frac{1}{S} \sum_{s=1}^{S}E(f(x_s)) = \phi$? I think $p(x_1) = p(x_2)$...$=p(x_S)$ in this case but how can it be always the same?

Comment: $\Bbb E[f(X)]$ is completely determined by the function $f$ and the distribution of $X$, as is evident from your first equation. Since $X_i$ have the same distribution (iid) $\Bbb E[f(X_i)]$ are identical.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri why you deleted theproof of $E[f(x)-f(y)]=0$, I think this proof is convincing.